Expo go crashing on start screen of my app after i Upgraded to SDK 51 from SDK 50
if you're facing crashes in the ios app after routing then you should install react-native-reanimated, ive answered what to do in the replies below

Welcome to StackOverflow. When sharing your solution to a problem, instead of directly including it in your question, consider asking a question and then answering it yourself. This will help others to search more effectively.

Ahh, did not know that, hopefully its better now

Can you give a bit more details about the crash you were having? I am currently having a crash of ExpoGo mentioning non-std C++ exception. It gives a stack that ends up with RCTConvertArrayValue.

again sorry for the late reply, i had a working application at SDK 50 before upgrading all the dependencies, the expo app had stopped working since it required that i upgrade my dependencies otherwise it would not have worked, and i did what every sane person would, upgraded my dependencies but it caused the entire application to stop working, it did give a RCT error but i cant quite remember which one, anyways, i had a hierarchy where all my files were getting the style from a layout.jsx, so i just imported the react-native-reanimated into that file and it started working without any issues

if you are still facing any issues, heres the github repo the working react native app, https://github.com/C33NIE/Airly, if you go through the files, you should be able to see if theirs anything you are missing that could be useful to your project

do
npx expo install react-native-reanimated
and then import into rootlayout that you have
import 'react-native-reanimated'
i was facing this issue, if you had it too, heres the fix

I tried this fix to my problem, but it did not solve it. Could you please explain a bit more what the fix consists in ? Why just including react-native-reanimated solves it?

sorry for the late reply, i had gone through the documentation of expo router, the creator had actually included this fix, but not many people could find it, anyways, his fix mentioned adding the react-native-reanimated to it, and he said he didnt know why but it just fixed the problem. so i cannot really explain it to you since even the creator doesnt know why it worked
